# JMETER Login test failing with the session

Tags: jmeter

Good morning, I'm trying to track my app I found a problem. I want to apply my own stress test using Jmeter.

I'm working on the Login (with a blazemeter test that I just recorded) but it doesn't work and the error message says: class `org.icefaces.application.SessionExpiredException` in the Response data (Response Body) of our POST request.

The POST request (Login form) has this parameters;

[image]

I have tried to set a parameter with the value of the session (that I got in the cookie when I go to the homepage) and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test structure is not correct as it is missing [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) bit.

You should design your test plan as follows:

1. Open login page (HTTP [GET](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) request)
2. Extract all the dynamic parameters using suitable JMeter [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), in particular for HTML response type the recommended Post-Processor is [CSS Selector Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS_Selector_Extractor), you will need to handle at least the following parameters:

   - `javax.faces.ViewState`
   - `ice.window`
   - `ice.view`
   - etc.
3. Amend your recorded POST request and replace hard-coded values with the variables from the Step 2.

Alternatively you can use another recording solution which provides automatic correlation benefit, to wit it automatically detects dynamic parameters and handles them. Check out [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) article for more details.

Comment: That was it for this problem, so its not about the IDSESSION of the page, thanks a ton.